# Set disk I/O priorities in Win7 or only allow disk access to specific processes (via batch file)?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, io, priority

The former would be more elegant but the latter is also fine for my purposes (and probably the more errorproof solution).
I capture 720p50-HDTV losslessly (ULH0/ULH2) and my archive-drive is fast enough but as soon as one additional process starts accessing the drive, I get dropped frames and out-of-sync audio which I really want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/), it gives you an option to save IO priorities for processes.

[image]

If ProcessHacker is running in background, the next time your tool gets started, it changes the IO priority automatically to the stored value.

Normally all processes have `normal` IO priority, so set your recording tool to `high.`

Comment: Doesn't work. Copying files to the drive restricts the bandwidth of the recording tool, even when the I/O priority is set to High in Process Hacker.
I think I need to find a way to completely take away access permission from all unwanted processes.

Comment: Sorry but access permissions go by security ID (user and group IDs), not by process. i.e. you can't restrict access to a drive to a process running a particular executable. You can restrict it to processes running under a particular user ID, or with a particular group membership. ... um, there IS the "claims-based access control" but that's only on Server editions.

Comment: You made it sound like it's possible on Win7 or am I misunderstanding?
Create another user without access to the harddrive and then create a batchfile that runs the capture software as admin via password prompt (who has access to the harddrive).
The problem is that system processes will still have access to the harddrive, correct?
Man, the limitations of Windows are beginning to show... You sure there  is not some tool or "driver hack" that could make this advanced control over disk I/O possible and intercept unwanted commands?

Comment: ...Stupid 5 minute edit limit. I just wanted to add "Lastly, would it be possible under Linux?"